# Make inDesign text box spacing behave like MS Word

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, paragraph, margin, spacing

In MS Word, if two paragraphs have, for example, before and after spacing: 10 pt, the space between each other will be 10 pt. They override each other.

With inDesign the spacing is additive: if two text objects have before and after spacing of 10 pt, the spacing between the two will be 20 pt.

I want inDesign spacing behave like MS Word.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're looking for does not exist in INDD. Agree with Wolff, you need to use what's available, and the "Ignore" setting can be useful to control spacing between same-style paragraphs. INDD is built for complex typesetting, and people do use it for complex work, so in my opinion it has everything you need, and there is no comparison to MS Word. Also don't confuse text boxes (what you call text objects) with paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't always force a program to behave like another. It's better to accept the logic of each program and get the best out of it.

In InDesign *Space Before* and *Space After* are added as you say. You can't really change that.

There is a setting for paragraphs called *Space Between Paragraphs Using Same Style* but, as the name indicates, it only applies between paragraphs with the same style so its use is pretty limited in my opinion. I never use it myself.

[image]

In your case, the real solution would simply be to set *Space After* to *0.5 inch* and leave *Space Before* at *0*.

[image]

Why would you even need the *Space Before* if you want it to be ignored anyway?

Comment: Thank you Wolff, can't believe I didn't see the space between paragraphs using the same style. That would've been really helpful. I will use it in the future.

Also thanks for taking your time to answer my question with great detail!

Comment: @Nicolas, you're welcome! I also initially thought space between paragraphs using the same style would be useful but as I said, I can't really see the need for it. You can't for example use it for numbered lists because the first item must have a separate style to restart the numbering and then it breaks. Anyway, if you found the answer helpful, remember to *accept* it.

Comment: Oops, just accepted it. I'm new to the stackexchange. I found some uses. For example, when doing bullet lists, I can set space between paragraphs of same style to 0,2 cm and then normal spacing to 0,5 cm. Same for numbered lists. I don't use the built in lists since they backfired in MS Word when converting the book to EPUB. After 20 days of inDesign, it really grew on me. The word spacing quality is unmatched, and the books I do have really improved in quality!